# selenium python -element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on 'view details' button but unable to so that for this particular [link](https://www.tesla.com/inventory/new/ms)
I have tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="View Details"]').click()
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include context to your source code in order to receive the proper responses. 
Please check the documentation [on how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you used any wait before that, may be you can use something 
 like 'element_to_be_clickable'.

Comment: Are you sure there is a single element exists in xpath: '//button[text()="View Details"' ? If not I think, you should use driver.find_elements_by_xpath

Comment: @ansu5555 yes i have used time delay

Comment: @VidyaSagar I am trying to do it for multiple .... but for an instance i have tried to click on atleast one of them , but unable to do it

Comment: Please give bit of more detail, as far I can guess with limited information you didn't find the desired element using `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="View Details"]')` SO, all you can try is: elements = `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[text()="View Details"]')` and then try clicking on all the element one by one. I would say finding lement by xpath is also not good idea.